# Change selected row checkbox value in Serenity platform

Tags: typescript, model-view-controller, serenity-platform

This question is related to Serenity platform development.

I've a grid using __id as idfiled:

```
protected getIdProperty() { return "__id"; }
```

I also added a checkbox for each row:

```
 this.rowSelection = new Serenity.GridRowSelectionMixin(this);
```

The question is: How to change the value of the check box from __id to use one of the column values (example: StudentID not always unique)

Thanks

Comment: @volkanceylan please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getSelectedKeys().map(x => 
        this.view.getItemById(Q.toId(x))
              .StudentID).filter(x => x != null)
```